# Como criar uma função para percorrer página PHP criada dinamicamente e mudar determinado texto

Tags: php

Tenho uma página PHP que é montada dinamicamente, e preciso alterar determinados textos, de acordo com o usuário ser homem e mulher.

Eu estava usando assim:

```
function mudasexocaps($sexo) {

    if ($sexo == "feminino") {
        echo "A";
    }
    else {
        echo "O";
    }
}

function mudasexo($sexo) {

    if ($sexo == "feminino") {
        echo "a";
    }
    else {
        echo "o";
    }
}
```

E daí no HTML:

```
<p><?php mudasexocaps($sexo) ?> cliente ?> ></p>
```

Mas dai que que os textos aumentaram muito, e fiquei pensando se não é possível fazer uma função com `preg_replace` ou algo assim, que percorresse o arquivos atrás dos textos, sem necessidade de toda vez incluir a função no HTML...

Basicamente, o arquivo é assim:

principal.php

```
(a função acima)
include texto1.php
include texto2.php
etc..
```

texto1.php

```
<p>O cliente ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin hendrerit accumsan lacus eget luctus. Ut ligula mi, ullamcorper quis diam sed, cursus gravida sem.</p>
```

texto2.php

```
<p> Loren ipsum o cliente dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin hendrerit accumsan lacus eget luctus. Ut ligula mi, ullamcorper quis diam sed, cursus gravida sem.</p>
```

Então resumindo tenho dois tipos de texto pra trocar: `O cliente` e `o cliente`, respectivamente para `A cliente` e  `a cliente`.

Existe uma forma de fazer isso? Como?

Comment: você pode usar um *placeholder* definido com, por exemplo, dois colchetes: `$texto = "Loren ipsum [[o]] cliente"`, utilizar `str_replace('[[o]]', mudasexo($sexo), $texto)` e `str_replace('[[O]]', mudasexocaps($sexo), $texto)`

Comment: Use uma view. É mais fácil! Veja minha resposta ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Idéia inicial:

Utilizei um pequeno texto, mas isto serve perfeitamente para uma página completa em HTML. Segue um esboço do que você pode fazer, de maneira bem simples:

```
$oa = ( $sexo == "feminino" )? 'a':'o';
$texto  = "Olá, car$oa cliente!\n";
$texto .= "Seja bem-vind$oa à nossa central de atendimento!\n";
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lEvzcJ)**.

Caso precise mudar várias palavras (serve para maiúsculas e minúsculas):

```
if ( $sexo == "feminino" ) {
   $oa = 'a';
   $hm = 'mulheres';
} else {
   $oa = 'o';
   $hm = 'homens';
}

$texto  = "Olá, car$oa cliente!\n";
$texto .= "Seja bem-vind$oa à nossa central de atendimento para $hm!\n";
```

Caso o texto venha pronto, de outro lugar ou template, você tem como fazer um *replace*. Basta deixar uma marcação especial no texto original:

```
$texto  = "Olá, car#oa# cliente!\n";
$texto .= "Seja bem-vind#oa# à nossa central de atendimento para #hm#!\n";

if ( $sexo == 'feminino' ) {
   $texto = str_replace ( '#oa#' , 'a'       , $texto );
   $texto = str_replace ( '#hm#' , 'mulheres', $texto );
} else {
   $texto = str_replace ( '#oa#' , 'o'     , $texto );
   $texto = str_replace ( '#hm#' , 'homens', $texto );
}
```

Note que desta vez fazemos a substituição depois do texto já existir. Nas anteriores, fazemos a mesclagem do texto após definirmos as variáveis.

A mesma técnica pode ser usada para maiúsculas e minúsculas, bastaria definir, por exemplo `#oa#` e `#OA#` nos templates.

### Aplicando os conceitos em uma função mais completa:

Com esta função, fazemos o `str_replace` em um *loop*, pegando de um *array* associativo as palavras desejadas:

```
function substituir( $texto, $arr ) {
   foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      $texto = str_replace ( $key, $value, $texto);
   }
   return $texto;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
$texto  = "Olá, car#oa# cliente!\n";
$texto .= "Seja bem-vind#oa# à nossa central de atendimento para #hm#!\n";

$masculino = array( '#oa#' => 'o', '#hm#' => 'homens'   /*, etc */ );
$feminino  = array( '#oa#' => 'a', '#hm#' => 'mulheres' /*, etc */ );

$texto = substituir( $texto, $sexo == 'feminino' ? $feminino : $masculino );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/HkUsGO)**.

### Utilizando o que o PHP já tem "embutido":

Esta sintaxe é mais confusa para listas longas de palavras, mas o `str_replace` do PHP também aceita *arrays*, eliminando a necessidade de uma função extra:

```
$texto  = "Olá, car#oa# cliente!\n";
$texto .= "Seja bem-vind#oa# à nossa central de atendimento para #hm#!\n";

$placeholders = array( '#oa#','#hm#'     /*, etc */ );
$masculino    = array( 'o'   ,'homens'   /*, etc */ );
$feminino     = array( 'a'   ,'mulheres' /*, etc */ );

$texto = str_replace( $placeholders, $sexo=='feminino'?$feminino:$masculino, $texto );
```

Mais uma vez, veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/0jwTyE)**.

### Notas:

- Nos primeiros exemplos, estamos utilizando a substituição de variáveis do próprio PHP.
- No segundo caso, utilizei os símbolos `#oa#` e `#hm#`, de maneira similar à sugestão que o usuário @Sançao fez nos *comments*.

  Utilizei o caractere `#`, mas pode ser qualquer outra coisa que facilite seu trabalho, desde que seja uma *string* que não coincida com alguma informação real do texto que não deve ser substituida. Se usássemos `[batata]` e `[pipoca]`, daria na mesma.
- Em princípio, **não há necessidade de funções multibyte**. Se você utilizar o mesmo encoding no `$texto` e nos valores do *array*, o *encoding* é irrelevante, pois a busca literal sempre vai funcionar.

Comment: Excelente resposta @Bacco! Parece bem mais simples e eficiente do que vinha fazendo... Mas só pra eu entender um ponto, então não tem mesmo um jeito de varrer o código HTML (que é incluído por `include` na página PHP, encontrar onde está escrito `caro cliente` (sem marcações), e se o sexo for feminino, mudar pra `cara cliente`? (é que são  muitos arquivos... rsrs) Muito obrigado! +1

Comment: @gustavox dá pra trocar qualquer coisa que você quiser, 'caro' por 'caro' ou 'cara', 'amigo' por 'amigo' ou 'amiga', mas os efeitos colaterais vão te dar mais trabalho do que você imagina. Vai ter situações que o 'caro' vai fazer parte de outras palavras, e ser trocado indevidamente. Mesmo que sejam muitas páginas, tenho certeza que o tempo que você vai perder com as marcas é menor do que fazendo remendos ;)

Comment: @gustavox pense com carinho na versão "marcada" :) A sua não deixa de ser marcada, o problema é a chance de confusão. E tem mais: Se são poucas palavras, você pode muito bem dar um _search & replace_ nos seus fontes, trocando "A Reclamante" por "#Reclamante#" em todas as páginas, com um editor de código (automaticamente), e assim com as outras palavras chave.

Comment: O bom de vc dar o search e replace é que, de "brinde", vc ja vai detectar os possíveis problemas que teria sem as marcações. E um exemplo de search & replace adequado: "O cliente" substituir por "#OA# cliente" (tou usando a palavra cliente como "ancora" pra nao trocar os "O"s errados)

Comment: Então, só pra constar que deu certinho aqui. Usei `ob_start` e `ob_get_clean` pra criar a variável `$texto` no arquivo `principal.php`, e funcionou perfeitamente. Usei a solução com o `#oa#`, e fiz o search e replace em todos os arquivos pela IDE em questão de microssegundos. :) Só fiquei na dúvida se posso ter problemas de performance, já que ele está fazendo essa varredura no arquivo renderizado inteiro antes de imprimir na tela, mas ainda não fiz nenhum teste, e acho que isso já é outra história. :) Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Isso é o fundamento de um sistema de templates. Eu ia sugerir que o @gustavox usasse um, mas isso é simples, dá conta do recado e, principalmente, não é uma caixa-preta. +1

Answer (score 2):

Caro Gustavox, veja se isto te ajudaria:

```
$texto1 = file_get_contents('texto1.php');
echo str_replace('O Cliente','A Cliente',$texto1);
```

Podendo inclusive alterar o str_replace e criar a sua própria função.
Obs.: Isto é só um pequeno exemplo.

Comment: No caso eu usei com `ob_start` e `ob_get_clean` pra criar a variável, mas foi basicamente esta solução que usei, só que como função simples (assim pude colocar ainda outras regras...), a segunda que o Bacco postou. De qualquer forma valeu a força. +1 .

Answer (score 1):

Quando se trata de textos variáveis misturados com texto estáticos, a melhor solução seria utilizar uma view (ou algo parecido) ?

Vou criar uma view simples para você entender.

Exemplo:

```
function view($view, array $data)
{
   unset($view, $data); // Por causa da colisão de nomes do extract

   ob_start();

   extract(func_get_arg(1));

   include func_get_arg(0);// Equivale ao caminho da view  

   return ob_get_clean();

}
```

Criar a página que vai ser carregada pela função `view`.

Exemplo `pagina.php`:

```
<div><?=$_client?> está sempre acima de todos!</div>
```

Você poderia gerar duas páginas diferentes apenas fazendo assim:

```
echo view('pagina.php', array('_cliente' => 'a cliente'));

echo view('pagina.php', array('_cliente' => 'o cliente'));
```

A saída nesse caso será:

a cliente está sempre acima de todos!

Eu preferiria fazer algo do tipo, já que isso torna uma view totalmente reutilizável.

Ainda teria um terceira opção, que é utilizando uma `Closure` nesse parâmetro.

Assim:

```
$sexo = $_GET['sexo']; // Apenas um exemplo 

$closure = function($sexo)
{
   if ($sexo == 'M') {
       $cliente = 'O cliente';
   } else {
      $client = 'A cliente';
   }

   return $cliente;
};

view('pagina.php', array('_cliente' => $closure, 'sexo'=> $sexo));
```

`pagina.php`

```
<div>Chamando como função anônima <?=$_client($sexo)?> que sempre acima de todos!</div>
```

O resultado poderia ser tanto `O cliente`, como `A cliente`, dependendo do parâmetro dado.

Comment: Solução interessante. +1

Answer (score 0):

É bom você simplificar o código. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

function acertaTexto( $texto, $sexo = 'masculino' ) {
    if ( $sexo === 'masculino' ) {
        $Ao = 'Ao';
        $ao = 'aa';
        $O  = 'O';
        $o  = 'o';
        $a  = '';
    }
    else {
        $Ao = 'À';
        $ao = 'ao';
        $O  = 'A';
        $o = 'a';
        $a = 'a';
    }
    eval( '$retorno = "' . $texto . '";' );
    return $retorno;
}
$textoOriginal  = '$Ao senhor$a Fulano! $O senhor$a pode comparecer...';
$textoFinal     = acertaTexto( $textoOriginal );
```

Daí você pode configurar seu texto como quiser. A variável $a só deve ser utilizada quando a palavra modificar apenas no feminino. Outra coisa, lembre-se de escapar o cifrão ($) quando quiser utilizá-lo de fato no texto. 
**Exemplo:**

```
$textoOriginal  = '$O senhor$a deve R\$ 20,00...';
$textoFinal     = acertaTexto( $textoOriginal );
```