# Alterando texto em vários lugares diferentes da página HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou pensando em desenvolver um sistema de [i18n](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(software)) para uma aplicação.

**A minha ideia é**: existe um texto **#i18n_label_name** em um determinado lugar da página e **#i18n_label_contact** em outro lugar.

**Pergunta**: Qual a forma mais performática para varrer toda a página buscando esses identificadores e alterando eles para o texto de tradução.

Comment: ja tentou usar uma library js para fazer isto ? http://i18next.com/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues não tinha conhecimento desta lib, muito legal, porém eu quero desenvolver a minha própria, e pensei em algo bem simples, sem necessidade de atributos ou algo exceto o texto.

Comment: você usa algum template engine  ou pretende escrever do zero em js puro ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues pretendo fazer em js puro.

Comment: Para quem precisar de coisa deste tipo _server side_, tenho uma solução em PHP aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97733/70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando *replaces*, em relação a [jquery.html vs innerHTML](https://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-innerhtml-the-better-way), a segunda opção se mostrou consideravelmente mais rápida em cerca de 29% sobre a primeira. Isso é uma diferença um tanto considerável, sem levar em conta o tempo de carregamento da Jquery, ao contrario do InnerHTML que é nativo de *Javascript*.

Porém, nesse [segundo teste](https://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/24), o *innerHTML* se mostrou mais lento em relação ao *jquery.append* e *jquery.html*.

Mas como assim???

O que acontece aqui é o seguinte, note que no primeiro exemplo o código é escrito da seguinte forma:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var html = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    html += '<div>Test ' + i + '</div>';
}

list.innerHTML = html;
```

Já na segunda:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + '<div>Test ' + i + '</div>';
}
```

Ou seja, os dois testes tem finalidades parecidas porém em questão de performance nota-se um numero bem distinto, isso se deve ao acesso do *innerHTML* na segundo teste ser feito dentro do próprio *for*, pode parecer algo bobo, mas a cada *looping* o mesmo é acessado e esse pequeno deslize pode gerar uma lentidão catastrófica.

Agora mais um porem em relação a segurança...

Segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML): "[...]recomenda-se que você não use o *innerHTML* quando estiver inserindo texto puro como alternativa, utilize *node.textContent*. Esse não interpreta o conteúdo passado como *HTML*, mas em vez disso, insere-o como texto puro."

Esse trecho diz respeito a execução de `<script>` e falhas de seguranças no uso do *innerHTML* (para mais detalhes sugiro que veja o link) e como alternativa sugere-se o uso do *[node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)*.

O *node.textContent* representa o conteúdo do nó do elemento e de seus descendentes e a principal diferença entre ele e o *innerHTML* é que o primeiro não analisa a HTML como um todo, apenas o *textNode* fazendo com que o mesmo seja mais performático em relação ao segundo.

Existem [diversos outros métodos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext) como: *innerText* e *nodeValue*, não falarei detalhadamente de todos para que o conteúdo não fique muito extenso mais com uma breve pesquisa você pode ver o que cada um faz. Bem vamos ao que importa, [esse teste](https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-innertext/17), inclui todos os métodos nativos citados testado em elementos diferentes.

Mas, qual usar? O *textContent* nesse ultimo teste se mostrou mais performática em relação aos demais totalizando média de aproximadamente 15% em comparação as outras formas. Acredito que a melhor forma com base no que foi descrito acima, tanto em relação de segurança quanto a performance é utilizar o mesmo. Outro ponto a levar em consideração e o fato de ser nativo de *Javascript*.

---

Em relação a seletores nativos o seletor *getElementByID* é mais rápidos em relação aos seletores como *getElementsByClassName* e *querySelector* segundo [esse teste](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/28). O Id também ganha no teste de seletores em *Jquery* [nesse teste](https://jsperf.com/comparacao-de-performance-entre-seletores).

Qual usar? no [primeiro teste](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/28) e [nesse terceiro](https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/25) pode-se ver claramente que novamente funcionalidades nativas saem na frente em relação a performance.

---

Os dois primeiros testes foram retirados do [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393981/append-vs-html-vs-innerhtml-performance).

[Aqui há](https://rafaelsoaresdev.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/analise-de-performance-em-javascript/) uma listagem de outros tópicos interessantes em relação a performance em javascript, recomendo como leitura adicional.

Obs.: os valores podem variar em milésimos dependendo da maquina e navegador.

Answer (score 5):

acredito que a melhor maneira de se fazer isto, é fazendo uso de propriedades `data-custom` e um json com os valores.

```js
i18n = {};
i18n["pt"] = {
  "name": "Nome",
  "contact": "Contato"
};

i18n["es"] = {
  "name": "Nombre",
  "contact": "Contacto"
};

i18n["fn"] = {
  "name": "Nom",
  "contact": "Contact"
};

i18n["en"] = {
  "name": "Name",
  "contact": "Contact"
};

var language = document.getElementById("language");
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll("[data-i18n]");
var onLanguageChange = function (event) {  
  [].forEach.call(elementos, function (elem, indice) {
    elem.textContent = i18n[language.value][elem.dataset.i18n];
  }); 
};

language.addEventListener("change", onLanguageChange);
onLanguageChange();
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="language">
    <option value="pt">Português</option>
    <option value="es">Español</option>
    <option value="fn">Français</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>  
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  Name: <label data-i18n="name"></label>
</div>
<div>
  Contact: <label data-i18n="contact"></label>
</div>
```

Segue uma implementação usando `class` ao invés de `data-custom`

```js
i18n = {};
i18n["pt"] = {
  "name": "Nome",
  "contact": "Contato"
};

i18n["es"] = {
  "name": "Nombre",
  "contact": "Contacto"
};

i18n["fn"] = {
  "name": "Nom",
  "contact": "Contact"
};

i18n["en"] = {
  "name": "Name",
  "contact": "Contact"
};

var language = document.getElementById("language");
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll("[class*='i18n']");
var onLanguageChange = function (event) {
  [].forEach.call(elementos, function (elem, indice) {
    var propName = [].filter.call(elem.classList, function (classe, indice) {
      return classe.indexOf("i18n") >= 0;
    })[0].split("-")[1];
    elem.textContent = i18n[language.value][propName];
  }); 
};

language.addEventListener("change", onLanguageChange);
onLanguageChange();
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="language">
    <option value="pt">Português</option>
    <option value="es">Español</option>
    <option value="fn">Français</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>  
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  Name: <label class="i18n-name"></label>
</div>
<div>
  Contact: <label class="i18n-contact"></label>
</div>
```

E por fim a solução usando substituição de strings, neste caso todo o HTML é recriado, então todas as consultas aos objetos DOM precisam serem refeitas e os eventos re-associados.

```js
i18n = {};
i18n["pt"] = {
  "name": "Nome",
  "contact": "Contato"
};

i18n["es"] = {
  "name": "Nombre",
  "contact": "Contacto"
};

i18n["fn"] = {
  "name": "Nom",
  "contact": "Contact"
};

i18n["en"] = {
  "name": "Name",
  "contact": "Contact"
};

var template = document.body.innerHTML;
var language = document.getElementById("language");
var onLanguageChange = function (event) {  
  document.body.innerHTML = template.replace(/{{i18n-(\w*)}}/g,function(m,key){
    return i18n[language.value].hasOwnProperty(key)? i18n[language.value][key]: "";
  });
  
  language = document.getElementById("language");
  language.addEventListener("change", onLanguageChange);
};

onLanguageChange();
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="language">
    <option value="pt">Português</option>
    <option value="es">Español</option>
    <option value="fn">Français</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>  
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  Name: <label>{{i18n-name}}</label>
</div>
<div>
  Contact: <label>{{i18n-contact}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Não queria utilizar data custom, será que fica muito complicado sem ?

Comment: você pode tentar simular o mesmo efeito usando o class, porém terá um trabalho adicional, uma outra opção é realizar um replace no innerHTML, porem teria de manter um "template" em memoria. teria algum problema com os `data-custom`?

Comment: Pelo fato de querer desenvolver isto para apex o data custom não é viável.

Comment: @devgaspa, atualizei a resposta, adaptei o script para usar uma `class` no lugar do `data-custom`

Comment: @devgaspa, adicionei um terceiro exemplo usando manipulação de string.

Comment: Neste terceiro exemplo a manipulação da string ficou excelente, exceto pelo jeito como foi tratado a busca e atribuição das strings. Muito obrigado pela disposição e tempo, irei usar esta forma de substituição da string como você fez, ficou legal mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar Jquery

```
$("#i18n_label_name").html("TEXTO");
$("#i18n_label_contact").html("TEXTO");
```

Com esse seletor $("#i18n_label_name"), ele vai direto no elemento, sem precisar varrer todo o HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando somente JS com a função `[querySelector()][1]`

```
document.querySelector("#i18n_label_name").innerHTML = "Novo Texto";

document.querySelector("#i18n_label_contact").innerHTML = "Novo Texto";
```

Answer (score 1):

Pela simplicidade, sugiro fazer um método em jQuery, mas se quiser escrever um pouco mais e ficar independente da biblioteca, pode fazer conforme o exemplo sugerido pelo @TobyMosque:

**O conteúdo em HTML:**

```
<select name="translate" id="tradutor">
    <option value="pt-BR">Portunguês</option>
    <option value="en-US">Inglês</option>
    <option value="es-GT">Espanhol</option>
    <option value="pe-PG">Língua do P</option>

</select>

<div data-translate="pt-BR">
    <p data-i18n="content_A">The Book's on the table</p>
    <p data-i18n="content_B">Hello World</p>
    <p data-i18n="content_C">My name is Ivan</p>
</div>
```

**E o javascript:**

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
        var el_translate = document.querySelector('[data-translate]');
        var tradutor = document.getElementById('tradutor');

        tradutor.value = el_translate.dataset.translate;        
        tradutor.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
            el_translate.dataset.translate = event.target.value;
            setLang(el_translate);
        });
        setLang(el_translate);
    }
}

var setLang = (function() {
    var i18n = {
        "pt-BR":{
            "content_A":"O livro está sobre a mesa",
            "content_B":"Olá Mundo",
            "content_C":"Meu nome é Ivan",
            "content_PT":"Português",
            "content_EN":"Inglês",
            "content_ES":"Espanhol",
            "content_PE":"Língua do P",

        },
        "en-US":{
            "content_A":"The Book's on the table",
            "content_B":"Hello World",
            "content_C":"My name is Ivan",
            "content_PT":"Portuguese",
            "content_EN":"English",
            "content_ES":"Espanish",
            "content_PE":"Language of P",
        },
        "es-GT":{
            "content_A":"El libro está en la mesa",
            "content_B":"Hola mundo",
            "content_C":"Mi nombre es Iván",
            "content_PT":"Portugués",
            "content_EN":"Inglés",
            "content_ES":"Español",
            "content_PE":"Idioma hacer P",
        },
        "pe-PG":{
            "content_A":"PO PliPvro PesPtá PsoPbre Pa PmePsa",
            "content_B":"POPlá PMunPdo",
            "content_C":"PMeu PnoPme Pé PIPvan",
            "content_PT":"PPorPtuPguês",
            "content_EN":"PInPglês",
            "content_ES":"PEsPpanhol",
            "content_PE":"PLínPgua Pdo PP",
        }
    };

    return function (e) {
        var elementos = document.querySelectorAll("[data-i18n]");
        [].forEach.call(elementos, function (el, index) {
            el.textContent = i18n[e.dataset.translate][el.dataset.i18n];
        }); 
    };
})();
```

## Aqui o exemplo funcionando e JavaScript Puro




## E aqui o exemplo funcionando com jQuery

> **Editado:** Conforme sugestão de @TobyMosque, que achei muito bem-vinda, uma adaptação sem uso de jQuery:

Comment: o AP deixou claro que pretende usar apenas JavaScript sem jQuery, quanto ao seu método `setLang`, sugiro que faça uma `closure` e declare o `i18n` dentro do mesmo, assim evitando instanciar o o mesmo sempre que o método `setLang` for executado. segue o seu script com as minhas sugestões de melhoria: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/hafm38x6/6/)