# Gravando variáveis no banco de dados e como recupera-las e atribuir valor

Tags: php

Estou precisando gravar um contrato em formato HTML no banco de dados. Esse contrato terá os dados pessoais das pessoas. Esses dados pessoais virá de uma consulta em banco de dados. Preciso preencher dinamicamente esses dados.

Formato Gravado no Banco de dados

```
<html>
....
Nome: $nome
.....
</html>

<?php
$contrato = $contratobanco;
echo $contrato;
?>
```

Preciso preencher esse campo $nome. Como gravar essa referencia no banco de depois recupera-las para atribuir corretamente na variável $contrato com o nome da pessoa preenchido vindo de uma consulta BD ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você não mencionou de onde vem as variáveis, vou dar um exemplo geral de um sistema de *templates*:

Informação do DB:

```
<html>
    Nome: $nome$
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $contrato = /* aqui você pega do DB os dados */;
    $nome = 'José Maria'.
    $idade = '17';

    $contrato = str_replace( '$nome$', $nome, $contrato ); 
    $contrato = str_replace( '$idade$', $idade , $contrato ); 
    ... faça o mesmo para todos os campos ...

    echo $contrato;
?>
```

Notar que no DB compensa usar uma marcação que não confunda, como `$nome$` em vez de `$nome`, pra não ter ambiguidade caso haja algo como `$nomenclatura` (que começa com `$nome` também).

Se já tiver muita coisa no DB, tenha ao menos o cuidado de, com palavras iniciadas da mesma forma, trocar as mais longas primeiro na sequência dos *replaces* (trocar o `$nomenclatura` antes de `$nome`, senão o `$nome` vai mexer em coisa que não deve).

Veja a sintaxe do `str_replace` usando *array* para fazer várias substituições de uma vez só:

```
    $contrato = str_replace(
       array( '$nome$', '$idade$', '$endereco$' ), // Palavras a trocar
       array(  $nome  ,  $idade  , $endereco    ), // O que vai por no lugar de cada uma
       $contrato
    )
```

A pergunta a seguir pode ajudar também:
[Como criar uma função para percorrer página PHP criada dinamicamente e mudar determinado texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97672/)

Comment: Isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Para inserir dados na base de dados crie um formulário com os inputs necessários. Na action desse form aponte para um arquivo chamado `insere.php`.

`formulario.html`

```
<form action="insere.php" method="post">
Nome:<br>
<input type="text" name="nome"><br>
Contrato:<br>
<input type="text" name="contrato">
</form>
```

`insere.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

//PEGAR OS VALORES DO FORMULARIO
$nome=$_REQUEST['nome']; /*Aqui o nome é o `name="nome"` que vem do   formulario via POST.*/
$contrato=$_REQUEST['contrato'];//A mesma coisa

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO info (nome, contrato)
VALUES ('$nome', '$contrato')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Pronto foi adicionado na sua bd.

Agora vamos criar o `mostra.php` onde ele vai exibir os dados que existem na sua tabela `info`.

`mostra.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT nome, contrato FROM info";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//MOSTRA O RESULTADO
    echo "nome: " . $row["nome"]. " - Contrato: " . $row["contrato"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Pronto, espero que isto tenha ajudado. Para mais informações sobre O `INSERT` e o `SELECT`, porfavor consulte:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

*Configure o utilizador/senha/nome da base de dados, assim como o nome da sua tabela

Comment: Obrigado. Acho que não expliquei direito. O Valor da variável $nome não será gravada no banco de dados. O Modelo do contrato será gravado. Os dados para preenchimento desse contrato virá de outra tabela. Então preciso saber uma forma de gravar essas referencias das variáveis desse contrato no modelo e depois atribuir o valor correspondente que virá do banco de dados. Deu para endernder? gravado no banco: <html>.... Nome: $nome ...</html> ai preencher esse $nome com um valor que virá do bando de dados, da tabela clientes.